# beginBitmapFill and optimization as3, flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Sorry for the broken English - Google translator.
As written in the optimization tips - rasterized vector objects preferable.
If you create multiple bitmaps and invest in them a link to a bitmapData, the memory does not increase. 
What happens when beginBitmapFill repeat option is set to true?
All repeats refer to a single cell with the pixels in the memory?
And another question - in terms of optimization, beginBitmapFill considered as a bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instantiate any object it will consume some amount of memory. If you are creating new Bitmaps and reusing the same `BitmapData`, it will consume some amount of memory. When `beginBitmapFill` `repeat` option is set to true, it copies the passed bitmap data to fill empty space. That bitmap data is stored alongside the object, and is reused whenever you transform your object to fill accordingly.

When you use `beginBitmapFill` the object is still treated and rendered as a vector. You can change it to `sprite.cacheAsBitmap = true;` if you want it to be rendered as a bitmap.

---

Adobe on `cacheAsBitmap`:

> If set to true, Flash runtimes cache an internal bitmap representation
>   of the display object. This caching can increase performance for
>   display objects that contain complex vector content.